# what's the technical difference between express and http, and connect for that matter

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express

```
var express = require("express")
  , app = express()
  , http = require("http").createServer(app)
```

I constantly see these being put on the dependencies. From my point of understanding, http hosts front-end html? and express holds server-sided nodejs logic? and connect was the base layer of express so is that also a server-sided module?

If that's not the case why not people just do

```
express().listen(8080)
```

instead of

```
require("http").createServer(express()).listen(8080)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Express` is another layer on top of `http`. It takes care of basic repeated tasks that are required for an web application. `connect` is a middleware, which too takes care of basic repeated tasks that are required for an web application.

The whole idea, behind using any framework is to stay **DRY**, Don't Repeat Yourself. Tasks like, **parsing the body** of the request, **parsing cookies** are very much required for every web-application. `Express` provides them by **default**.

In the Express 4.x, most of it has been refactored in to several granular modules, like `body-parser`, `morgan` etc. One can use them directly without using express.
Please refer [Express - GitHub](https://github.com/expressjs) for complete set of modules.

`Express` is another layer on top of `http` means `Express` internally uses `http`. In other words, it is a wrapper over `http`. If you look at the source code of `Express`, you will find that it internally uses `http`. Please refer the highlighted statements at
https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L540-543

Comment: also, what does it mean to have express in an layer on top of http?

Comment: @user2167582 **DRY** stands for **Don't Repeat Yourself**, stated in the answer. I will updated the answer to address your second concern.

Answer (score 0):

**Lets take an example to understand the difference between `http` module and `express` module.**

for an instance consider `http` module is a car i.e an average comercial car.

where on the other hand, consider `express` as a super car.

See, `http` module provides various tools (functions) to do things for networking like making a `server` ,`cilent` etc.

where as `express` is build upon the top of `http` module with some more usable and better functionalities like easy ways to handle `routes` ,easy ways to make `firmware, servers, client` etc.

just like a difference between normal car and super car (may be luxury car) .They both are cars at the end of the day but features are more in luxury car with ease of use just like in `express.js`

[Source](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Express-and-the-HTTP-module-in-Node-js)

Comment: Express is a web server framework for building applications. It's not a 'super car' vs a 'car' it's a 'car' vs an 'engine'. HTTP is the engine. It facilitates the connections and requests made much like the engine in a car facilitates movement. Express, like the car surrounding the engine, is what makes the engine useful.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference, you can see the code of express.listen() in the [github repo](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L615)
This code calls the function createServer from the HTTP module. In other words, this is more like a shortcut.