# what is the difference between using Express GET method and HTTPS GET method in the below code?

Tags: node.js, express, https, get, web-development-server

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const https = require("https");

app.get("/", function (req, res){
  var url = "https://***";
  https.get(url, function(response){
    console.log(response);
  });
  res.send("server running");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Express is really just a layer on top of http.
I reckon those following links might help you out, this question has been asked.

- [what's the technical difference between express and http, and connect for that matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25151726/whats-the-technical-difference-between-express-and-http-and-connect-for-that-m#:%7E:text=Express%20is%20another%20layer%20on,required%20for%20an%20web%20application.&text=Tasks%20like%2C%20parsing%20the%20body,Express%20provides%20them%20by%20default.)
- [Difference between a server with http.createServer and a server using express in node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35167824/difference-between-a-server-with-http-createserver-and-a-server-using-express-in/35167883)

Answer (score 0):

`app.get()` registers a listener for a specific INCOMING http request path on a local Express server.

`https.get()` makes an OUTBOUND https request TO some other https server to fetch content from that other server.

And, obviously, the `https.get()` is using https, not http.  The `app.get()` could be listening for either - it depends upon how the server it is part of is started (as an http server or an https server) which the code you have in your question does not show.